# Is there a pattern for prototypal inheritance with privates/protected

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, private, public

The problem with most approaches to privates/protected in Javascript Objects is, that they use closure. By this they have to be defined in the constructor and all public methods that want to access them have to be defined in the constructor as well.

This makes two things impossible:

- Instances of the object that share a public methods instance. Each instance of the object must have its own instance of each method that can access private members
- Children being able to access and reuse protected methods from their parents

Is there a way to fix those two issues, so private methods can be shared across all instances, as well as children being able to reuse their parents protected methods.

Also decent browser support, at least on ECMA5 level would be awesome.

Comment: Children shouldn't be able to use or access private methods from their parent, only protected ones.

Comment: `WeakMap`s could be used to solve most of the problems related to private *data*. I'm sure this has been asked / discussed before. OTOH, why enforce a model onto JavaScript objects that they are not designed for?

Comment: @ssube Maybe wording is wrong. But if I have a function that does some complicated stuff and want to reuse it on a child, without this method being public, how would I call this? Or why shouldn’t I want to do that? Maybe I have some error in reasoning I am missing.

Comment: @FelixKling WeakMaps sound quite cumbersome for that purpose. Also the browser support isn’t to good. But I’ll have a look into it.

Comment: How private do you need it to be? Using Symbols would prevent any accidental use of the private method, and you wouldn't need to create new functions in the constructor like you're doing below.

Comment: @MarcusBlättermann That would be a protected method, rather than private. Private (in most languages) specifically means that nobody, not even descendants, can touch it. JS doesn't have much support for protected methods, but Typescript has them (or pretends to), so you might want to check how they do it.

Comment: @squint Do I? There are no functions in the constructors. That was acutally part of the whole idea. And browser support for Symbols is basically non-existing.

Comment: @ssube Thanks. I changed the wording in the question.

Comment: @MarcusBlättermann: The `.bind()` method creates a new function object. So for each instance, you're creating the `FooConstructor` object, the `exports` object and a new function object for each public method. The browser/transpiler support [isn't bad](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Symbol), so one way or another you can use these today.

Comment: @squint Oh god point, didn’t thought about that bind would kind of undermine, the whole point of shared functions.

Comment: @squint Thanks for the hint. Did a little test. Calling a function that goes through a `bind` is about 8 times as slow as calling it directly (the function itself doesn’t do anything). 

So if the function gets called a lot from the outside, that’s bad. If it gets called only rarely from the outside, but the private functions get called alot, then it wouldn’t be a problem.

On the other hand, people keep invoking jQuery objects all over the place … ;)

Comment: @MarcusBlättermann how did you benchmark a single function call? You need to make sure the VM can't inline it or optimize it out, which means passing something to and from the function (at least) and making sure the VM is warmed up, the method is considered hot, and all optimizations have already been applied. It's effectively impossible to test a single call on its own at this point, since JS runtimes are pretty smart.

Comment: @MarcusBlättermann: yeah, bound functions have had a history of being slower, depending on the implementation. The amount of allocation that takes place in jQuery apps is pretty insane, IMO. But then I tend to lean heavily toward low memory use, especially because of the GC.

Comment: @ssube just called a method that did nothing, thousands of times, and measured the time with performance.now(). Tryed it again, with the function doing something, but the result remains the same. I guess I will stay away from `.bind` in the future, when it comes to methods being called quite often.

Comment: `bind` is slow when you first call it, but should have minimal or no cost after that. Calling a function that does nothing will almost certainly be optimized out and yield mostly-random results.

Comment: @ssube I did several test, with different setups, all give the same order of magnitude for a `bind` call of. To put it into perspective: one call takes about about  0.00001ms, which means calling about 10-90k functions with `bind` will slow down your program for about a millisecond, compared to calling them without `bind`. So actually, its not really that bad.

Comment: @MarcusBlättermann this literally just came to me while reading your comment, but I wonder if the VM can inline and/or totally elide function calls that it knows are going to a no-op function (your direct call) but is unable to do so when calling a bound function, since that function is created at runtime and not part of the original program (meaning it can change). Can you post your benchmark or adjust it to make sure both functions are actually being invoked?

Comment: @ssube I added something to my original answer, on how to switch between using `bind` and the classical way. Just do this, and call `fooInstance.publicMethod()`as often as you like. No matter, what the method does, the time difference stays about the same, even when I add heavy stuff like `Math.random()` and let it change a global var.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be a perfect and elegant solution, I figured out a way to fix the problems stated above

## Constructor

First a look at our constructor, with some prototypal methods.

```js
function FooConstructor(args) {
    this.args = args;
    this.private = "lower case secret from foo";

    this.exports = {
        publicMethod: this.publicMethod.bind(this)
    };
}

FooConstructor.prototype.privateMethod = function() {
    return this.private;
}

FooConstructor.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
    return this.privateMethod().toUpperCase();
}
```

Not the objects `this.exports`. Here we will store all the things that should be made public.

Whats important for this to work is, that we don’t call the constructor directly, but rather use a Factorymethod, that gets an instance of the object and then only returns the `exports` object.

```
function getInstanceFoo(args) {
    return new FooConstructor(args).exports;
}
```

Now if we want an instance of Foo we just do.

```
var fooInstance = getInstanceFoo("fooArg");
```

From this instance we can only access the stuff we put into the `exports`object.

```
fooInstance.publicMethod(); // "LOWER CASE SECRET FROM FOO"
fooInstance.private;        // undefined
fooInstance.privateMethod;  // undefined 
                            // calling it would give you: 
                            // Uncaught TypeError: fooInstance.privateMethod is not a function
```

## Children Constructor

The good thing is now, that our factory exports, only the stuff we want public, but we still have a constructor, that can be accessed. So for a child we can do:

```
function BarConstructor(args) {
    // this will just copy all the exported methods from Foo
    FooConstructor.call(this, args);

    // overwrite stuff we don’t want from the parents constructor
    this.privateMember = "lower case secret from bar";

    // add publics that should be exported for the child
    this.exports.newPublicMethod = this.newPublicMethod.bind(this);
}

BarConstructor.prototype = new FooConstructor();

BarConstructor.prototype.newPublicMethod = function() {
    return "My args: " + this.args;
}

function getInstanceBar(args) {
    return new BarConstructor(args).exports;
}

var barInstance = getInstanceBar("barArg");

barInstance.publicMethod();    // "LOWER CASE SECRET FROM BAR"
barInstance.newPublicMethod(); // "My args: barArg"
barInstance.private;           // undefined
```

## Summary

So that’s it. This does pretty much, what we want.
Here you can try it out:

```js
 // FooConstructor ------------------------------------------
 function FooConstructor(args) {
  this.args = args;
  this.privateMember = "lower case secret from foo";

  this.exports = {
   publicMethod: this.publicMethod.bind(this)
  };
 }

 FooConstructor.prototype.privateMethod = function() {
  return this.privateMember;
 }

 FooConstructor.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
  return this.privateMethod().toUpperCase();
 }

 // FooFactory
 function getInstanceFoo(args) {
  return new FooConstructor(args).exports;
 }

 // BarConstructor ------------------------------------------
 function BarConstructor(args) {
  // this will just copy all the exported methods from Foo
  FooConstructor.call(this, args);

  this.privateMember = "lower case secret from bar";
  this.exports.newPublicMethod = this.newPublicMethod.bind(this);
 }

 BarConstructor.prototype = new FooConstructor();

 BarConstructor.prototype.newPublicMethod = function() {
  return "My args: " + this.args;
 }

 // BarFactory
 function getInstanceBar(args) {
  return new BarConstructor(args).exports;
 }

 // Get Instances ------------------------------------------
 var fooInstance = getInstanceFoo("fooArg"),
  barInstance = getInstanceBar("barArg");

 console.log( "fooInstance.publicMethod(): " + fooInstance.publicMethod() );
 console.log( "fooInstance.private: " + fooInstance.private );
 console.log( "fooInstance.privateMethod: " + fooInstance.privateMethod );


 console.log( "barInstance.publicMethod(): " + barInstance.publicMethod() );
 console.log( "barInstance.newPublicMethod(): " + barInstance.newPublicMethod() );
 console.log( "barInstance.private: " + barInstance.private );
```

## Downsides

There is on thing, that might be downsides, even though it might be possible to find work arounds for those as well. You have to decide if these are deal breakers.

`instanceof` won’t work.

```
fooInstance instanceof FooConstructor; // false
```

## Slow `bind`

If you fear `bind` will slow down your program and the overhead is not necassry, you can always go back to a non-private version, by changing the constructor to this:

```
function getInstanceBar(args) {
    return new BarConstructor(args);
}
```

And remove the `this.exports` from your constructor. So you can easily switch between the two without much refactoring. Also in that case, it might be a good idea to additionally add an underscore to all private members.